# Open a new ssh window

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, putty

I am currently using CYGWIN, Git Bash, and Msysgit, plus Putty and I want to open a new window at the same location from one to another. Is there a command similar to `start .` or `explorer .` to open CYGWIN from Git Bash, or Msysgit from CYGWIN?

Comment: Not sure how ssh ties into this. You want to open an explorer window? From a remote login via ssh? or what...?

Comment: `cmd /c start .` would be answering cygwin to cmd. I'm trying to git-bash to cygwin

Answer (score 1):

In cygwin bash, doing `explorer .` **does** open a new explorer window wherever you are at the time.

Comment: I rephrased the question. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create script in your PATH to run cygwin shell directly. something about "start c:/cygwin/bin/sh"